# React Firebase Authentication with Google

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have google sign in React component as below. This user login is working fine. And then I load home page and home page has user image in the header section.

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { GoogleAuthProvider, signInWithPopup } from "firebase/auth";

import "firebase/auth";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { auth } from "../firebase";

const provider = new GoogleAuthProvider();

const SignIn = () => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
  console.log(user);
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  // Get initial theme from local storage (if available)
  useEffect(() => {
    const isDark = localStorage.getItem("theme") === "dark";
    if (isDark) {
      document.documentElement.classList.add("dark");
    } else {
      document.documentElement.classList.remove("dark");
    }
  }, []);
  const handleGoogleSignIn = async () => {
    try {
      const result = await signInWithPopup(auth, provider);
      const credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credentialFromResult(result);
      console.log(credential);
      const user = result.user;
      setUser(user);
      navigate("/");
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error signing in with Google:", error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="flex flex-col items-center justify-center h-screen dark:bg-neutral-800">
      <button
        type="button"
        className="text-white bg-[#4285F4] hover:bg-[#4285F4]/90 focus:ring-4 focus:outline-none focus:ring-[#4285F4]/50 font-medium rounded-lg text-sm px-5 py-2.5 text-center inline-flex items-center dark:focus:ring-[#4285F4]/55 me-2 mb-2"
        onClick={handleGoogleSignIn}
      >
        <svg
          className="w-4 h-4 me-2"
          aria-hidden="true"
          xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
          fill="currentColor"
          viewBox="0 0 18 19"
        >
          <path
            fillRule="evenodd"
            d="M8.842 18.083a8.8 8.8 0 0 1-8.65-8.948 8.841 8.841 0 0 1 8.8-8.652h.153a8.464 8.464 0 0 1 5.7 2.257l-2.193 2.038A5.27 5.27 0 0 0 9.09 3.4a5.882 5.882 0 0 0-.2 11.76h.124a5.091 5.091 0 0 0 5.248-4.057L14.3 11H9V8h8.34c.066.543.095 1.09.088 1.636-.086 5.053-3.463 8.449-8.4 8.449l-.186-.002Z"
            clipRule="evenodd"
          />
        </svg>
        Sign in with Google
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default SignIn;
```

Then I have another component to get the signed in user.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { onAuthStateChanged } from "firebase/auth";
import QuizCard from "./components/quiz-card";
import HomeLoading from "./components/home-loading";
import QuizHomeLayout from "./components/quiz-home-layout";
import { auth } from "../firebase";

const QuizHome = () => {
  const [homeData, setHomeData] = useState(null);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);

  async function fetchQuizData() {
    try {
      const serverHomeData = await fetch(
        `https://storage.googleapis.com/kobello.appspot.com/home.json`
      ).then((res) => res.json());
      setHomeData(serverHomeData);

      setLoading(false);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchQuizData();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
      if (user) {
        setUser(user);
        console.log(user);
      } else {
        console.log("No user is signed in.");
      }
    });
  }, []);

  if (loading) {
    return <HomeLoading />;
  }
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <QuizHomeLayout user={user}>
        {homeData &&
          homeData.map((data, key) => <QuizCard key={key} data={data} />)}
      </QuizHomeLayout>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

export default QuizHome;
```

This component works fine just after the sign in and if I refresh the web page onAuthStateChanged return no user. How to get the logged in user anytime inside any component ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following to get the current logged in user,

```
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";

const auth = getAuth();
const user = auth.currentUser;

if (user) {
  // User is signed in, see docs for a list of available properties
  // https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/auth.user
  // ...
} else {
  // No user is signed in.
}
```

Reference: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users